# how to listen to collection changes on mongodb in express with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have tried to listen to changes in a collection of mongodb using express, but it seems to do not trigger the listener despite not showing errors when connecting to DB.

I initialize my db in a database script `database.js` like this:

```
import { connect } from "mongoose";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";
        const targetDatabse = process.env.DB || "mongo-test";

        const db = await connect(uri + targetDatabse);
        console.log('DB connected to', db.connection.name);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e);
    }
})

();
```

Then that gets imported to `server.js` which contains my main server.

```
import express from 'express';
import "./database.js" // <-- Imported database connection
import Task from './models/Task.js';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.json())

Task.watch().on('change', change => console.log("Change!")); // <-- Not working

app.get('/tasks/find', async (req, res) =>
{
    try
    {
        const tasks = await Task.find();

        res.json(tasks);
    }
    catch({ message })
    {
        res.status(500).send(message);
    }
}) 

app.post('/tasks/add', async (req, res) => // <-- route to add a doc (receives a JSON)
{       
    const { title, description } = req.body;

    try
    {
        const task = Task(
        {
            title: title,
            description: description
        });
        const taskSaved = await task.save();

        res.send('Task added!');
    }
    catch({ message })
    {
        res.status(400).send(message);
    }
});

app.listen(port);

console.log('Server started on port: ' + port);
```

And this is the task model if needed:

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const taskSchema = new Schema(
{
    title: 
    {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    description: 
    {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    done: 
    {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
}, 
{
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false
});

export default model("Task", taskSchema);
```

How can I solve this, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Seems i can't use change streams like i wanted to beacuse I need to be connected to a replica set (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/change-streams.html)